# Are locally small categories enough?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, set-theory

Besides category theory itself, is there any part of mathematics that categories that are not locally small play an important role?

Moreover, I don't understand why people care about size issues of category theory. I feel like category theory is just a type of language that we use when we **cheat**, i.e. we want to use a single definition to mean lots of things and see what are true under that definition. However, when these ideas are applied to sets, then we don't have to worry about all consistency problems arising due to size issues.

For example, for a given abelian category $\mathscr{A}$, we can construct the category of chain complexes $Kom(\mathscr{A})$ and show that this is an abelian category again. So we can form a finite iteration $Kom(...Kom(\mathscr{A})...)$. With this in one hand, when this is directly applied to $\mathscr{A}=$**Ab**, we can formulate this purely in the zone of ZFC. So I don't see "embedding category theory into ZFC" is a big deal, since when we apply categorical ideas to sentences formulated just with sets, all proofs can be purely written in **ZFC**. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Most  natural categories are not small. Modules, sheaves, spaces... Moreover, essentially all operations we can do we can do on sets, so we have to be careful that we do have sets.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Edited!

Comment: Also, I feel like this type of question was asked a lot about set theory as well. You could do category theory naively, just as you probably use set theory (unless you are in that field) and most likely no bunnies will be harmed in the process. But you do need solid logical foundations for any theory and when you try to do purely categorical constructions, things can quickly get out of hand. For example, you mention category of chain complexes, everything is fine, but what about derived category? Localization of locally small category needs not be locally small.

Comment: Non-locally small categories are useful even if you are only interested in locally small ones. Sometimes you want to construct a locally small category, and you start by constructing a category which in principle may or may not be locally small and, once you have it, only *then* prove that it is locally small. This is very useful, and similar to the way in which we often show that a differential equation has a solution in some generalized sense (say, in distributions) to immediately show that that solution is actually a good ol' function.

Answer (score 4):

Categorical language would be useless in its role as a conceptual shorthand in important applications such as algebraic geometry or algebraic topology, if it were restricted to small categories. This is not because such language is **cheating** but because ZFC is not an adequate practical universal language for mathematics. In the example you give, the category of all abelian groups $\mathbf{Ab}$ does not comprise a set in ZFC and that severely limits what one can conveniently say about it in ZFC. E.g., you can't quantify over all functors from $\mathbf{Ab}$ to itself. You can translate most proofs that use categorical language into "morally equivalent" proofs in ZFC, but the translations will generally involve complications about set-theoretical issues that are irrelevant to the underlying mathematical ideas. ZFC is a great technical tool, but it is not the ultimate right way to formalise mathematics  - we haven't discovered that yet $\ddot{\smile}$.